# Performance comparison between file.copy and filestream copy method

Tags: vb.net, filestream, system.io.fileinfo

I have a windows application(VB.net) which involves copying a huge number of files to a specified location, and performance is the issue i need to check on.
I have two ways of doing this:File.Copy and other using Filestream.
Which one of the above option is faster? and is there any other faster way to achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you do you own benchmark test and see which is faster?

Comment: I dont have enough time to test them both,though searched on net and found that File.Copy is relatively faster than filestreaming.

Comment: Yet you have enough time to post the question and wait while someone else does the test for you?

Comment: `File.Copy` is a single method call; using `FileStream` relies on your code intelligently buffering and managing access.  You need to have an implementation that uses `FileStream` before you can compare these directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`File.Copy` is faster(*)

*(*) Why would you trust a opinion in a forum? Instead of being here waiting for an answer you could be doing a test to see which method is faster*